# Error while downloading a file from url

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to read a file from url and making it a `File` Type.

Below is the code

```
public File fileFromUrl(String str) throws IOException
      {
          File file = new File ("image.png");
          URL url = new URL (str);
            InputStream input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            try {

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (file);
                try {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                } finally {
                    output.close();
                }
            } finally {
                input.close();
            }
          return file;
      }
```

However I am experiencing error at  `OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (file);`

Kindly tell me how can I make `File` of my `url`

Comment: add `file.createNewFile()`  before `OutputStream output = ...`

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of the exception. Also do an `exists()` check on the file before any operation

Comment: I want to make a temp file. I dont want to store it anywhere but remain in temp memory

Comment: @Chris its null pointer at file is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine. Instead of `File file = new File ("image.png");` use absolute path for the file. Like `File file = new File ("<absolute-path-from-root-directory>");`

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you have posted the exception that you are getting, but my guess is that you don't have write permissions to the current working directory in which you are trying to create your output file.

If you want to see where it tries to write the file, add this diagnostic to your program:

```
System.out.println(
  "Absolute path of image.png: <" + file.getAbsolutePath( ) + ">"
);
```

Comment: @umar. Please add an exception trace to your question.